# Installing Leksah with Nix on OS X

Tags: haskell, nix, leksah

I've installed Haskell using the "batteries included" [official version](https://www.haskell.org/platform/), which includes GHCi and Cabal. I then followed the [recommended guidelines](https://github.com/leksah/leksah#getting-leksah) for installing Leksah, first installing Nix (with `curl`, [as recommended](https://nixos.org/nix/)), then downloading Leksah from the Git repository and running `./leksah-nix.sh ghc843`. Basically, I've done nothing unusual, but I get this error:

```
joshf:leksah joshfriedlander$ ./leksah-nix.sh ghc843
./leksah-nix.sh: line 20: nix-build: command not found
./leksah-nix.sh: line 21: /bin/ghc: No such file or directory
./leksah-nix.sh: line 22: nix-build: command not found
./leksah-nix.sh: line 48: /bin/launch-leksah: No such file or directory
```

Is it not finding `nix-build`? Should I move it? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Specs: I'm using an MBP with Mojave 10.14.2.

Comment: One of the following files should have a line of code which "sources" `~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`: .bash_profile, .bash_login and .profile  Have you tried opening a new terminal and trying to run `nix-build --help`?

Comment: Hi, and thanks. My `bash_profile` does contain this line: `if [ -e /Users/joshfriedlander/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh ]; then . /Users/joshfriedlander/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh; fi # added by Nix installer`. And the `nix.sh` script does exist there.

Comment: Hang on, I think just `touch`ing my `.bash_profile` may have changed something - the script is running now. Will update or possibly delete the question. Thanks again!

Comment: Yup, looks like that did it.